# Crash on Multidimensional Float Array Allocation

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to allocate a very large multidimensional float array but an hitting out of memory exception issues when going above certain dimensions.

```
//Doesn't crash
float[,] newArr = new float[40000, 5000];

//Crashes
float[,] newArr1 = new float[45000, 5000];

//Doesn't crash
float[,] newArr2 = new float[40000000, 5];

//Crashes
float[,] newArr3 = new float[45000000, 5];
```

I am not sure what the issue is, I'm aware of array size limits of 2GB and 4 billion elements, but neither of these approaches either limit. Also, I cannot use another data struct because I need to pass the [,] to an external API call. Anyone have a clue what might be going on here? 
Thanks!

Comment: Its happening on my 32 bit application @ .NET 4.5.1, Windows 7, 8 GB RAM.

Comment: 45000 x 5000 x 4 ~= 900 megabytes.  You are not going to get that in a 32-bit process, the largest hole in the available address space hovers around ~650 megabytes at startup and that goes rapidly downhill when your program has been running for a while.  Just remove the jitter forcing so your program can run as a 64-bit process.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Compile tab.  Lots of really big holes in a 8 terabyte address space.

Comment: @HansPassant would love to mark that as an answer if you don't mind putting it in one :)

Comment: Just copy/paste/embellish the comment into a post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have experienced with your code is that it doesn't work when compiling (and running) in 32-bits mode. If I switch to 64-bits build mode, it does work.

So open your project settings > Compile and set Platform target to x64.

Answer (score 3):

From [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700362/crash-on-multidimensional-float-array-allocation#comment64778723_38700362):

> 45000 x 5000 x 4 ~= 900 megabytes. You are not going to get that in a 32-bit process, the largest hole in the available address space hovers around ~650 megabytes at startup and that goes rapidly downhill when your program has been running for a while. Just remove the jitter forcing so your program can run as a 64-bit process. Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Compile tab. Lots of really big holes in a 8 terabyte address space.